# Equivalent command to grep binary files

Tags: grep, binary

I have a bunch of binaries and I know that inside these binaries there are strings I want to find.

I want to do a:

```
grep -lir "the string I am looking for"
```

and get a list of all binaries inside a particular directory that contain that string but `grep -lir` is apparently not working with these files.

Is there a command that can do this kind of search from terminal?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), you can use [-a](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#File-and-Directory-Selection) option to make it treats binary files as text files:

```
grep -ali -- string file
```

If your grep version does not support `-a`, you can use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/) instead. With ack 1.x, you need to include `-a` option, with ack 2.x, you don't, since when searching include non-text file by default (only ignored non-text file when you did not specify any files).

Comment: Am I misreading `ack`'s self-description?  (in the manual) "ack 2.x will search through every regular, non-binary file that is not explicitly ignored [by blah blah]"  So it sounds like ack 2.x should still stop reading a file early if the contents look binary.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That's occured when no files were selected. Try `ack grep /bin/grep` and you will get the result. I updated my answer to prevent confusing.

Comment: Try using the strings command to get the strings from your binary.

Answer (score 44):

The command `strings` will extract all ascii data from a file, if you then `grep` its output, you can search for your data:

```
strings <filename> | grep "search text"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This binary is good fit for this task.

Comment: @xeon: It's not always good to use `strings`, read [here](http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/2014/10/psa-dont-run-strings-on-untrusted-files.html) for more details.

Comment: Since the goal is to determine *which* binaries contain the string, `strings -f` would be more appropriate.

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: the best answer. thanks a lot

Answer (score 16):

Your question is about find binary files that contain a pattern
(and we have already very good answers!). Complementary we may like to get the occurrences.

I often use

```
grep -aPo '.{0,20}pattern.{0,20}'  binfile
```

to get a surrounding context of 20-char.

Answer (score 0):

**`bgrep` if lines don't necessarily fit into memory**

I keep coming back to this random repo from time to time: https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep Install:

```
curl -L 'https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep/raw/master/bgrep.c' | gcc -O2 -x c -o $HOME/.local/bin/bgrep -
```

Use:

```
bgrep `printf %s saf | od -t x1 -An -v | tr -d '\n '` myfile.bin
```

Sample output:

```
myfile.bin: c80000003
\x02abc
myfile.bin: c80000007
dabc
```

I have tested it on files that don't fit into memory, and it worked just fine.

I've given further details at: [Best way to grep a big binary file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223078/best-way-to-grep-a-big-binary-file/758528#758528)