# Grep, but for binaries

Tags: grep, search, binary

I've got a fragment of an image file produced by data-recovery software.  I suspect the complete original is somewhere on my home fileserver.

If this were a fragment of a text file, I could just grab a unique-looking fragment, run `grep -r -l -F` , and come back in a few hours for the answer.  However, since this is a binary file, it's got all sorts of things that `grep` doesn't like (such as null bytes), and even if I can get past that, I don't know how to give `grep` input that isn't valid UTF-8.

How can I search for the original, preferably without writing my own search program?

(This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217936/equivalent-command-to-grep-binary-files): despite the likely-sounding title, that one is about finding strings in binary files, where I'm looking for binary data in binary files.)

Comment: The approach at [this answer to "How to know if a text file is a subset of another"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406053) also works for binary files.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
grep -a -r -l -F <fixed string> .
```

> -a, --text
> Process a binary  file  as  if  it  were  text;  this  is  equivalent  to  the --binary-files=text option.

or

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    strings "$1" | grep -lF <fixed pattern>
' sh {} \;
```

> strings - print the sequences of printable characters in files

Comment: In the general case, how would I get the "fixed pattern"?  For this particular file, `strings` produces some fragments that look unique (as well as several chapters of an ebook -- data recovery does funny things sometimes), but I can't count on that happening with any arbitrary file.

Comment: I dunno what exactly you are trying to do. The commands I gave are meant to search binary files as requested

Comment: The commands are half of what I need: how to search.  The other half is "what to search for": how do I pull a piece out of the file I've got and tell `grep` "search for this"?

Comment: open the recovered fragment file with a text editor ... copy a section ... confirm that grep finds the recovered fragment file ... then search for the original file ... actually Notepad++ can do what you are asking

Comment: @jsotola, the whole point of this question is that I'm dealing with a binary file, not a text file.  Opening it in a text editor will give me nothing useful, what with all the nulls, control characters, and other non-text things in the file.

Comment: @Mark you may be confusing a text editor with a word processor ... download Notepadqq text editor ... use it to open a binary file ... search for `\0` ... that should find a null

Comment: What notepad++ have to do here? Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files/98700#98700

Answer (score 0):

You could **first dump the binary file using [od](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html)** :

I suggest using the -x and -w256 options in order to reduce the size of the file and the number of lines in order to maximize grep efficiency and necessarily the -A n option in order to remove the needless offset address, let's have :

```
od -x -A n -w256 yourbinary_fragment > pattern.txt
```

You could also make aggressive use of the -j -N and -w options or even reedit pattern.txt in order to reduce the number of lines to some strict minimum. (In order to significantly ease grep's work)

Then **find for the files matching the patterns** after being themselves dumped

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    od -x -A n -w256 "$1" | grep -lFf pattern.txt
' sh {} \;
```

If using your machine for other purposes, I'd suggest to SCHED_BATCH that process.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl` and the Sys::Mmap module (in `libsys-mmap-perl` package on Debian):

```
fragment=/path/to/your/fragment
size=$(( $(wc -c < "$fragment") - 1 ))
find . -type f -size "+${size}c" -print0 | 
  perl -MSys::Mmap -l -0sne '
    BEGIN {
      open N, "<", $needle or die "$ARGV[0]: $!\n";
      mmap($n, 0, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, N);
    }
    if (open H, "<", $_) {
      mmap($h, 0, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, H);
      print if index($h, $n) >=0;
    } else {
      warn "$_: $!\n";
    }' -- -needle="$fragment"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect one file is the first part of a different file, you could take the first few bytes from both files and compare these:

```bash
# Omit or change the bytes arguments as needed, see `man head`
head --bytes=1032 file1.bin > /tmp/file1.head.bin
head --bytes=1032 file2.bin > /tmp/file2.head.bin
diff --text /tmp/file.head.*
```

You could also visually look at the files using `xxd /tmp/fil1.head.bin`. Finally, programs like Meld or Beyond Compare show you visual side-by-side comparisons of the files.

Comment: The problem with this is that the beginnings of binary files tend to be very formulaic.  For example, indexed Windows Bitmap files of a given size will tend to be identical for the first 1078 bytes.

Comment: For binaries you're indeed right, though it shouldn't be a problem for Image Files. Otherwise, it's simply a matter of grabbing the first 10k or so.